# How to show/hide elements in nativescript?

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I'm learning Nativescript and even though information and docs are very limited and bad, I'm trying to find my way around and learn it.

I'm currently trying to learn how to show/hide elements.

I found a code snippet on Google which supposedly does that but when i try the same code in my app, it does absolutely nothing. no errors either.

**my code in home.xml:**

```
<Button text="{{ showDetails ? 'Hide' : 'Show' }}" tap="toggle" />
<Label text="Lorem ipsum..." visibility="{{ showDetails ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}" />
```

**my code in home-view-model.js**

```
const observable = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");


var pageData = new observable.Observable();

exports.loaded = function(args) {
    pageData.set("showDetails", true);
    args.object.bindingContext = pageData;
}

exports.toggle = function() {
    pageData.set("showDetails", !pageData.get("showDetails"));
}
```

could someone please advice on this?

Comment: It seems to work perfectly fine - [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=Gh6I1G&v=1), if you still have issue please update and share Playground.

Answer (score 2):

A common CSS mistake. The property should be set to `collapse`, not `collapsed`. Not sure why they chose to go with a different verb tense for this, TBH.